# Can I search for how many checkins in a place with Facebook graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, checkin

I have read through graph API document, and tried the following queries:

> curl https://graph.facebook.com/search\?type\=checkin\&place.name\=Dante+Coffee\&access_token\=...

The access_token is valid. But it shows nothing like this:

> {"data":[]}

I guess I only have the permission to access checkins sent from the owner of this access_token. And since I have never checkin this place, I got zero data from this query. But is it possible to get the total number of checkins with a place name by Facebook Graph API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the [FB docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#searching) say that Checkins are searchable, `/search?q=woolwich&type=checkin` gives me an error `(#615) The checkin table does not support search.`.

But Places are searchable and the Place object has a `checkins` field (see `/205142516170657?fields=checkins`) - this should give you what you want.